# сохранить List в классе

Tags: c#, .net, list, сериализация

Здравствуйте, вопрос такой, можно ли сохранить список объектов в новом классе, без использования `xml/json/bin` сериализации, чтобы потом можно было взять этот класс вставить такую же программу и получить те же объекты. Я не знаю даже с чего начать. Вот мой список

```
List<Figure> figureList = new List<Figure>();
```

Добавляю обьекты по щелчку кнопки

```
Circle circle = new Circle(pbCanvas.Width, pbCanvas.Height, figureCounter);
figureList.Add(circle);
```

Comment: Вот этот самый процесс сохранения списка объектов, чтобы потом можно было открыть в другой программе, _и называется сериализацией_. Так что нет, провести сериализацию без сериализации не получится.

Comment: Объекты можно сохранять в [db4o](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o). Не уверен, что этот метод подойдет. Сам им не пользовался. Может быть там внутри сериализация и используется.